# How to select rows from pandas dataframe by looking a feature' data types when a feature contains more than one type of value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, row

I have a dataframe with 3 features: id, name and point. I need to select rows that type of 'point' value is string.

| id | name | point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x | 5 |
| 1 | y | 6 |
| 2 | z | ten |
| 3 | t | nine |
| 4 | q | two |

How can I split the dataframe just looking by type of one feature' value?

I tried to modify select_dtypes method but I lost. Also I tried to divide dataset with using

```
df[df[point].dtype == str] or df[df[point].dtype is str]
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the answer would be:

```
out = df[df['point'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

But this would also select rows containing a string representation of a number (`'5'`).

If you want to select "strings" as opposed to "numbers" whether those are real numbers or string representations, you could use:

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['point'], errors='coerce')
out = df[df['point'].notna() & m]
```

The question is now, what if you have `'1A'` or `'AB123'` as value?